# Installing pymc in Canopy EPD free using enpkg

Tags: python, pymc

I am trying to install pymc in enpkg but have hit a roadblock. What are the next steps?

Here is my bash:

```
(Canopy 32bit) new-host-2:~ [0003]$ enpkg pymc
prefix: /Users/[0003]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User
Versions for package 'pymc' are:
    2.1b0 (no subscription), 2.2.0 (no subscription)
You are logged in as [email deleted] ([username deleted]).
Subscription level: EPD Free
(Canopy 32bit) new-host-2:~ [0003]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/ this package is not included in the free version. You need to buy a subscription to get it.
Yes, this is one of the off-putting things with EPD, they charge a subscription for otherwise freely-available packages on pypi.

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages into Canopy, including the free version, using enpkg from the command line. Details here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-command-line